# jQuery DataTables check filtered rows checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

How to check checkbox in jQuery DataTable after searching

```
 $('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {

                table
                    .columns( 1 )
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();                                                
                  //Than ckeck on uncheck  checkbox in datatable first column
            } );
```

Comment: Is it checkbox in this particular column or common checkbox for entire row should be checked?

Comment: Is table filtering supposed to be performed or it's only checkbox checking should be done? If latter is the case, is it current page or entire table should be considered?

Comment: Checkbox in separate column, 
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='ck' class='ck' value='".mysqli_result($q1,$i,'id_prece')."'></td>";

table filtering supposed to be performed and than must be checked all checkboxes wich is in the 1 column of table   (as filtering result)

OR when users press button in the table selected all checkboxes which column Nr 3 have the value "farm"

Comment: Please, add the logic described in your comment to your question body. One more question from my end: what should happen when searchbar is cleared and all the entries become visible? Should all table rows get selected in that case?

Comment: Was the answer, I had given to your question, helpful?