# Selecting rows based on pre-made list in Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a page that my user interact with. They have to select around 200 rows from this table. But on average, 150 of those rows are usually pretty similar between users.

I want to add a couple of buttons that check those common rows for the user, that way they can then remove and add any remaining rows they want.

These buttons would either use a list from another file, or the list would be managed inside the jquery file.  The list would contain the Name/Region/Category/Class of the rows I wanted to select.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<script charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="samples" class="display nowrap compact hover dt-left" width="100%"></table>
    </table>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="JS/datatables.js"></script>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function () {    
  var table = $('#samples').DataTable( { 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "pageLength": -1,
    "lengthMenu": [[100, 250, 500, -1], [100, 250, 500, "All"]],
    ajax: "datatables.php",
    columns: [ 
      {data: '',
       defaultContent: '0',
       visible: false },
      {data: '',
       defaultContent: '',
       orderable: false,
       className: 'select-checkbox',
       targets:   1
      },
      {title : 'Sample Name', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 1},
      {title : 'Region/Program', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 2},
      {title : 'Class', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 3},
      {title : 'Category', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 4},
      {title : 'QC Concerns', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 5}
    ],
    select: {
        style:    'multi',
        },
    order: ([[ 4, 'asc' ], [ 5, 'asc' ], [ 3, 'asc' ]]),
    orderFixed: [0, 'desc'],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
     {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span> Download (ALL) or (SELECTED)',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 2, 5 ],
                modifier: {
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied'
                }
            }
        },
         {
            text: 'Use Selected Library',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config) {
            alert( 'This buton needs to pass the Sample Name and Category columns to php.' );
            }

             },
         {
                text: 'Upload Predefined Library',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, conf ) {
                    alert( 'This button needs to allow a csv file to be uploaded and passed to php.' );
                }
         }

     ]
  } );

  table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var row = table.row( dt );
        table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( '1' );
        table.draw();
    }
  });

  table.on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var row = table.row( dt );
        table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( '0' );
        table.draw();
    }
  });

} );
```

Data sample

```
const srcData = [
    {Name: '752', Region: '7', Class : 'unknown', Category : 'unknown', QC_Concerns: 'yes'},
    {Name: 'North 5th', Region: 'NWA', Class : 'unknown', Category : 'square', QC_Concerns: 'yes'},  
    {Name: 'Elmdale', Region: '6', Class : 'back', Category : 'circle', QC_Concerns: ''},  
    {Name: 'Rosebud', Region: '7', Class : 'back', Category : 'triangle', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Letterkenny', Region: 'GO', Class : 'back', Category : 'square', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: '632nd', Region: 'GO', Class : 'front', Category : 'ball', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Water', Region: '4', Class : 'front', Category : 'ball', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Dirt', Region: '1', Class : 'front', Category : 'mermaid', QC_Concerns: ''},
    ];
```

Comment: Can you give some example of what users may do and what is expected to happen with the table? Why filtering table can't be used to select similar rows?

Comment: The table is currently around 400 rows, but will grow to around 2000 rows over time.  A user will need to on average select 60 to 200 rows in order to continue to the next step.  For the larger selections, there will be a core group of rows that will be similar between all users. I want to select these rows with one click instead of 150 clicks.

Comment: Back to the second part of my question: wouldn't filtering similar rows by their common criteria and checking checkboxes for all filtered rows all at once do the job? That would be couple of clicks instead of one, but more intuitive, flexible and scalable in my opinion. For filtering examplesyou may check out corresponding section of datatables.net, also I may suggest this plug-in: https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter.

Comment: For checkboxes checking you may look into my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189111/jquery-datatables-check-filtered-rows-checkboxes/55218287#55218287

Comment: I would be open to that workflow. I have minimally tried to do multiple row selects, but anytime I make a second group select, it unselects the first group.

Comment: I've tried to use your plugin, is there some JS that needs to be added besides the sDom: 'tF'?  I've also added the link and script tags into my html.  The datatables native search is disabled, but nothing takes its place.